# Java Jackson deserialize to object from multiple json formats

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-annotations

Let's assume there are those 2 different json structures - both contain the same values, but the key hierarchy differs - one is flat, the other is nested:

1. Flat:

```
{
    "documentId": "7ef1229c-301a-40d9-8c0c-faf5da54785d",
    "first_name": "Xbyvuve",
    "last_name": "Abmhlakwd"
}
```

2. Nested:

```
{
    "_meta": {
        "_more_nested" {
            "documentId": "7ef1229c-301a-40d9-8c0c-faf5da54785d",
        }
    },
    "first_name": "Xbyvuve",
    "last_name": "Abmhlakwd"
}
```

Resulting in Object:

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
public class PersonDocument {
    String documentId;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
}
```

Is there a way in Jackson to instantiate the same object from both json strings without providing a custom deserializer? For instance with a special annotation? In addition, I also want the resulting json string on serialization to be like the "flat" json string.

Thank you in advance!

Tried different annotations without any positive result :<

Comment: You might want to add which combination(s) of annotations you have tried.

Comment: If you want to achieve this by sprinkling a couple of data-binding annotations, then unfortunately it's not feasible.